# How to apply custom graph to image?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

In shader editor, I want to add a specific value to a specific color value of an image. For example, you have a BW image and the BW value at pixel (x/y) is 0.5 and WHEN the value is 0.5, I want to add 0.3 to it. When the value is 0.4, I want to add 0.1 etc. Depending on what the BW value at this pixel is, I want to add a specific value to it, written as a function graph. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can reproduce said function using a bunch of math nodes. But you could also use a color ramp node, it literally remaps colors from BW data.

Comment: You can also have a look at a _Float Curve_ node. There you can add control points (similar to a _Color Ramp_ node) and design your function. A control point at (0.5 ; 0.8) would perform exactly what you described with "WHEN the value is 0.5, I want to add 0.3 to it".